# Wrong redirect when login in blazor application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, blazor-webassembly

I use ASP.NET Core 3.1 Blazor webassembly application (the default one created by Visual Studio 2019).

I hooked up ASP.NET Identity for user management, added scaffolded Identity item (login, registration etc)

When I click **Register**, the application correctly redirects to

```
https://localhost:44349/Identity/Account/Register
```

but if I click **Login**, the application redirects to

```
https://localhost:44349/Account/Login
```

which is wrong (I expect `https://localhost:44349/Identity/Account/Login`)

LoginDisplay.razor:

```
<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <a href="authentication/profile">Hello, @context.User.Identity.Name!</a>
        <button class="nav-link btn btn-link" @onclick="BeginSignOut">Log out</button>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="authentication/register">Register</a>
        <a href="authentication/login">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by replacing

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

with

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I resolved the issue